# Angular form to pristine when for is in original state

Tags: angularjs, forms, angularjs-scope, 2-way-object-databinding

I have a form with preset values from an object in scope. When I modify a form field for instance the name field and change it from Bob to Bobby the form is now `dirty` but if I delete the "y" and the "b" from the end of the name the form is now in its original state but it is still `dirty`. How do I get it to return to `pristine` when the form is the same as when it started out? I have the original state saved in scope so they can be compared but I am not connecting the dots on how to achieve this.

Here is an example that shows the same behavior I was describing above:

http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/forms/formreset/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like the below in your controller, and then use the ng-change to call the function.

```
$scope.resetWhenUnchanged = function()
{
    if (original === $scope.modifiedValue) {
        $scope.personForm.field.$setPristine();
    }
};
```

Comment: This seems to work but I guess when you set a form to pristine it submits the form which is an undesired effect.